# PCA -how are the principal components mapped?

Tags: r, pca

I have a problem with the `pca` in R, probably a simple one:

I have 10 Vectors a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j and bind them with `cbind`.

With the Result I perform a `pca`, using `prcomp`. I get the scores all right and also I get the principal components in descending order.

Only: how on earth do I know which of the components `a` to `j` is the first, which the second and so on?

Probably really a beginner's question - still cannot solve it and would appreciate some help.

Comment: There's no one-to-one correspondence between original dimensions and principal components -- that's the point of PCA :) The help for `prcomp` tells you what components its return value has; these should help you to figure out which original dimension contributes to which principal component.

Comment: but - where is the point if in the end you do not know  which components of the original data set are most important? I thought the whole idea was to find them?

Comment: What you want to do sounds more like [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection). [Principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) can help you to identify important features, but its purpose is really to transform the feature space.

Comment: Each principal component is a linear combination of all your original components. For example `prcomp(...)$rotation[,"PC1"]` shows you how much each of your original dimensions contributes to the first component. So it is not a one-to-one map like you thought but more like a many-to-many mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a old question... but maybe someone needs it in the future

```
library(stats)
data(USArrests) 
PCA.USA <- prcomp(USArrests[,c(1,2,4)], scale=TRUE) 
proporcionDeInfluencia <- abs(PCA.USA$rotation)
sweep(proporcionDeInfluencia, 2, colSums(proporcionDeInfluencia), "/")
```

More info in [Principal Components Analysis - how to get the contribution (%) of each parameter to a Prin.Comp.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760108/principal-components-analysis-how-to-get-the-contribution-of-each-paramete)

Answer (score 4):

The rotation matrix can tell you which original variables are important in each of the principal components. For example, the first column of the rotation matrix shows the contributions for PC1. A high value in the first row (relative to the other coefficients) means that the first original variable is important in the first principal component. Let's say that the first column has high positive values for the first five rows, and high negative values for the second five rows. This means that the PC axis can be interpreted as the ratio between those two groups.

Comment: That did help.... Is there any possibility to find the variation of each vector in the starting matrix to the principal components? I.E. I have Vectors 1 to n and PC 1 to PC n and I want the variation between pc1 and Vector 1 and so on?