# How to calculate the total contribution of a variable for 2 or more PCs in R (PCA)

Tags: r, pca, svd

I have used SVD to get the matrix V and D

```
a <- rnorm(10, 50, 20)
b <- seq(10, 100, 10)
c <- seq(88, 10, -8)
d <- rep(seq(3, 16, 3), 2)
e <- rnorm(10, 61, 27)

my_table <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e)
X<- as.matrix(my_table)
sv<- svd(X)
U<- sv$u
V<- sv$v
D<- sv$d
Z<- X%*%V

# I know V is loadings for each variable
V
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.47127774  0.1101038  0.84237687 -0.2330963 -0.04291587
[2,] -0.46309655  0.6788144 -0.19949420  0.5031776  0.17823289
[3,] -0.41041595 -0.7145416  0.02300398  0.5538093  0.11728268
[4,] -0.07145917  0.0415040 -0.03735585  0.2083779 -0.97383478
[5,] -0.62441269 -0.1216386 -0.49867688 -0.5851088 -0.06543590
```

D^2/sum(D^2) is the contribution of each PC for total variation.

How do you calculate the total contribution of a variable for 2 or more PCs?
e.g. how much variable b contribute to PC1 + PC2 + PC3?

I have read this [Principal Components Analysis - how to get the contribution (%) of each parameter to a Prin.Comp.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760108/principal-components-analysis-how-to-get-the-contribution-of-each-paramete/12760337#12760337)

Thanks,
Ming

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/51) PCA process (read First Principal Component, Second Principal Component), there should not be contribution of same parameters to different components. Correlation between parameters that have contributed to Principal Component 1 (PC1) and PC2 is 0.