# Identify Principal component from Biplot in R

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I'm doing a principal component analysis, after I got the analysis result, how to identify the first couple of principal predictors? As it is messy from the plot. It's hard to see the predictors names:
[image]

Which part of the PCA results should I look into? This is more like how to determine the most important predictors which could explain, lets' say 80%, of the variance of your data. We know, e.g, the first 5 component did this, while the principal component is just combination  of predictors. How to identify those "important" predictors.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example when you're asking a question. The code you use to run the pca is more important the biplot generated. Also, please define what you mean by 'first couple of principle predictors'.

Comment: @Adam Quek,This is more like how to determine the most important predictors which could explain, lets' say 80%, of the variance of your data. We know, e.g, the first 5 component did this. While the principal component is just combination  of predictors. How to identify those "important" predictors. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer [Principal Components Analysis - how to get the contribution (%) of each parameter to a Prin.Comp.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760108/principal-components-analysis-how-to-get-the-contribution-of-each-paramete)

The information is stored within your `pca` results.
If you used `prcomp()`, then `$rotation` is what you are after, or if you used `princomp()`, then `$loadings` holds the key.
Eg.

```
require(graphics)
data("USArrests")

pca_1<-prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
load_1<-with(pca_1,unclass(rotation))
aload_1<-abs(load_1)
sweep(aload_1, 2, colSums(aload_1), "/")
#               PC1       PC2       PC3        PC4
#Murder   0.2761363 0.2540139 0.1890303 0.40186493
#Assault  0.3005008 0.1141873 0.1485443 0.46016113
#UrbanPop 0.1433452 0.5301651 0.2094067 0.08286886
#Rape     0.2800177 0.1016337 0.4530187 0.05510509


pca_2<-princomp(USArrests,cor=T)
load_2<-with(pca_2,unclass(loadings))
aload_2<-abs(load_2)
sweep(aload_2, 2, colSums(aload_2), "/")

#            Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3     Comp.4
#Murder   0.2761363 0.2540139 0.1890303 0.40186493
#Assault  0.3005008 0.1141873 0.1485443 0.46016113
#UrbanPop 0.1433452 0.5301651 0.2094067 0.08286886
#Rape     0.2800177 0.1016337 0.4530187 0.05510509
```

As you can see, `Murder`, `Assault`, and `Rape` each contribute ~30% to PC1, whereas `UrbanPop` only contributes ~14% to PC1, yet is the major contributor to PC2 (~53%).

Comment: @j-con I have a relatively large dataset comprising of several psychological scores for 200 subjects in long format, giving me 20000 entries in the dataset. I would like to reduce dimensionality on this dataset by using PCA, how would you suggest I go about it? Thanks.

Comment: This is a really great step-by-step tutorial. https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/little-book-of-r-for-multivariate-analysis/latest/little-book-of-r-for-multivariate-analysis.pdf. Let me know if you get stuck