# How do I extract summary of PCA as a dataframe in R using Prcomp?

Tags: r, dataframe, pca

```
res.pca = prcomp(y, scale = TRUE)
summ=summary(res.pca)
summ
```

Gives me the output [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVSPI.png)

I want to change this Summary in to a Data Frame,

I've Tried to use the do.call(cbind, lapply(res.pca, summary)) but it gives me the summary of Min/Max but not the one I desire.

Please See That I dont want to extract values from column names, I seek a general solution That I can use.

Comment: When I try as.data.frame(summ) It says cannot coerce class ""summary.prcomp"" to a data.frame.

Comment: When I tried the tidy(summ) It says:  "No method for tidying an S3 object of class summary.prcomp , using as.data.frame"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the "element" `importance` of `summary(res.pca)`:

Example taken from [Principal Components Analysis - how to get the contribution (%) of each parameter to a Prin.Comp.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12760108/4137985):

```
a <- rnorm(10, 50, 20)
b <- seq(10, 100, 10)
c <- seq(88, 10, -8)
d <- rep(seq(3, 16, 3), 2)
e <- rnorm(10, 61, 27)

my_table <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e)
res.pca <- prcomp(my_table, scale = TRUE)

summary(res.pca)$importance 
#                          PC1    PC2    PC3     PC4       PC5
#Standard deviation     1.7882 0.9038 0.8417 0.52622 9.037e-17
#Proportion of Variance 0.6395 0.1634 0.1417 0.05538 0.000e+00
#Cumulative Proportion  0.6395 0.8029 0.9446 1.00000 1.000e+00

class(summary(res.pca)$importance)
#[1] "matrix"
```

---

**N.B.:**
When you want to "study" an object, it can be convenient to use `str` on it. Here, you can do `str(summary(pca)` to see where the information are and hence where you can get what you want:

```
str(summary(res.pca))

List of 6
 $ sdev      : num [1:5] 1.79 9.04e-01 8.42e-01 5.26e-01 9.04e-17
 $ rotation  : num [1:5, 1:5] 0.278 0.512 -0.512 0.414 -0.476 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
 $ center    : Named num [1:5] 34.9 55 52 9 77.8
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ scale     : Named num [1:5] 22.4 30.28 24.22 4.47 26.11
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ x         : num [1:10, 1:5] -2.962 -1.403 -1.653 -0.537 1.186 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
```

> ```
>  $ importance: num [1:3, 1:5] 1.788 0.64 0.64 0.904 0.163 ...
>  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Standard deviation" "Proportion of Variance" "Cumulative Proportion"
>  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
> - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.prcomp"
> ```

Comment: s <- data.frame(summary(res.pca)$importance) Solved the issue, Thanks.