# python-3: How to get contribution of each parameter in PCA (sklearn)?

Tags: python-3.x, pca

I would like to compute the contribution percentage of each original feature to PCA-values.

The question is exactly as [Principal Components Analysis - how to get the contribution (%) of each parameter to a Prin.Comp.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760108/principal-components-analysis-how-to-get-the-contribution-of-each-paramete) but for Python.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factor Loadings using sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217710/factor-loadings-using-sklearn)

Comment: Not really, but I am checking that.